# Array has 5 objects and each object has an array property of another 5 objects. I'm trying to make function that finds the object with ID

Tags: javascript

First of all, this is the JSON file which is used - https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.14.1/data/en_US/runesReforged.json

Currently I have this function that allows me to put a specific id as an argument and get one of the 5 main objects in that array:

```
findSummonerRune: (state) => (id) => {
    let rune = state.summonerRunes.find(rune => rune.id == id);

    return rune
}
```

So `findSummonerRune(8100)` returns the first object with `"key": "Domination"` property. However, if I try to find rune with id of `8112`, it doesn't work because that rune is a sub-rune which is found in the properties of rune with id of `8100`. More specifically, in the `slots` property.

Now I understand why my function doesn't work, it's made to find which one of the main 5 objects has a property id == id, however, I'm just not sure how to also loop through their array property slots to look for the other runes as well.

Comment: confused on one point, do you want to return the `slots` object or the main object that contains the id in it's slots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

personally, if you want to return the item from `slots`, I'd flatten my list once upfront:

```
state.flattenedRunes = state.summonerRunes.reduce((acc, rune) => 
                         acc.concat([rune], rune.slots.reduce((a, r) => a.concat(r.runes), [])), []);
```

and I'd just search that list instead

if you want to actually return the main object that contains the item in its `slots`, then do this to also check the sub arrays on your find.

```
let rune = state.summonerRunes.find(rune => rune.id == id || rune.slots.find(slot => slot.runes.find(r => r.id == id)));
```

Comment: I'm trying out the second code, but it's not working and console.log(rune) returns undefined

Comment: had a small bug due to the nested structure in slots, fixed now

Comment: Very strange, whenever I look for a rune with id of 8005, the rune returned is with id of 8000. Damn that's confusing.

Comment: like I said, method 2 is for finding the MAIN object that contains the rune. Method 1 is for finding the rune itself

Comment: Oh so I first flatten the arrays and then use my function on the flattened array?

Comment: yes. I'd personally just flatten the array one time up front for performance reasons

Comment: Yeah that works, though I'd have to inspect the code since it's very confusing. Thanks a lot.